# Match Regex in MySQL for repeated word

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I'm having a query problem. I use mysql as DB. I want to use a REGEX to match the result I expected and The Table is

```
table A

----------------------------------
|   ID  | Description            |
----------------------------------
|   1   |  new 2 new 2 new 2 new |
|   2   |   new 21 new 2 new     |
|   3   |   new 12th 2           |
|   4   |   2new 2new            |
|   5   |   new2 new 2new        |
```

The Result I expected 
- numeric 2 can only show twice 
- character after/before 2 must be varchar (except after whitespace)

```
Table B
    ---------------------------------
    |   ID  | Description           |
    ---------------------------------
    |   4   |   2new 2new            |
    |   5   |   new2 new 2new        |
```

The Query I've got so far:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE 
(description REGEXP '^[^2]*2[^2]*2[^2]*$')
```

[click here for sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1284e/2)

could anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Can you spell out your logic?

Comment: The Result I expected
- numeric 2 can only show twice
- character after/before 2 must be varchar (except after whitespace)

Comment: What does _"character after/before 2 must be varchar"_ mean?

Comment: @muhnizar You just copied and pasted from your question..  The reason he asked is that was _not_ a good enough explanation.  Please elaborate on what you want to happen (in detail please).  Thanks

Comment: @Alma character after/before "numeric 2" cannot be numeric like ID=2 and ID =3

Comment: @mmmshuddup no.. I never tried that before.

Comment: Ok I get it now.  I can't think of a good way to do that without lookbehinds/lookaheads and PCRE type regular expressions are apparently not supported by MySQL..  You should consider the idea that perhaps MySQL is _not_ the right "man" for the job here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below regex to get the Description of fourth and fifth ID's.

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE 
(description REGEXP '^2[^2]*2[^2]*|\w+2[^2]*2[^2]*$')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1284e/18

**Explanation:**

- Divide the above regex into two like `2[^2]*2[^2]*` as one part and `\w+2[^2]*2[^2]*` as another part. In regex `^` represents the starting point and `$` represents the end point.
- `2[^2]*2[^2]*`

  - `2` Matches the number 2.
  - `[^2]*` Matches any character not of 2 zero or more times.
  - `2` Matches the number 2.
  - `[^2]*` Matches any character not of 2 zero or more times.
  - This would get you the 4th ID.
- `|` A logical OR operator usually used to combine two regexes which means match either this(before) or that(after).
- `\w+2[^2]*2[^2]*`

  - `\w+2` Matches one or more word characters which should be followed by the number 2. In your example, 5th ID satisfy this regex.
  - `[^2]*` Matches any character not of 2 zero or more times.
  - `2` Matches the number 2.
  - `[^2]*` Matches any character not of 2 zero or more times.
  - This would get you the 5th ID.

Comment: the result is correct..but do you mind explain me the logic of the regex! thanks

Comment: I need another help from you.. do you mind? :) @AvinashRaj

I'm trying to change the expression to be more general (restricted to all digits) <br/> [sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcc49/1) <br/>
but somehow I always got the wrong result.
<br/>
sorry bothering you!

Comment: @muhnizar did you want the same id4 and ID5 values?

Comment: yes.. I still wanna get the same result id=4 and id=5

Comment: sorry I'm giving you the wrong data. 
Here is the right one   
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be368f/1